# SCHEDULE task for year or month

Tags: org-mode, org-agenda

I need to mark when I need to pay attention to a task in org-mode.

So far, I've been using `SCHEDULED` for this. In this sense, `SCHEDULED` may just mean "look at this on this date". This is my way of implementing a *variation of* of GTD. I know this may be abusing org-mode's `SCHEDULED` property.

One issue I have is that the model of tasks overlaps two concepts:

- Tasks that are indeed scheduled to be completed on a particular date.
- Tasks that I just need to look at on a particular date/period.

I could circumvent this by adding a new TODO state `SCHEDULED`. So far, instead, I've been using tags such as `nextweeklyreview`, etc.

This issue manifests when I plan tasks for future weeks: I can only plan them for a specific day (usually the first day of that week), making it look like Monday is going to be awfully busy.

What I really would like to do is to schedule a task for a week, or a month, or a year. I know I can add ranges, but that would make the task show up in red in the agenda if the start date is now past. It's also far too much work.

I want something like:

```
* A
  SCHEDULED: 2017
```

Or, alternatively:

```
* A
  :PROPERTIES:
  ON_DATE_YEAR: 2017
  :END:
```

Is any of this possible? How can I make it convenient to use?

*EDIT (2017/07/09 11:15CET, due to comment received): I really need to schedule a task for a week/month/year. This is not something that, afaik, GTD suggests, but I work best this way.)*

Comment: Have you considered using GTD keywords and then organize your `*Org Agenda*` search based on one or more of those keywords?  Your weekly/yearly stuff does not need to appear on the agenda view unless you want it to.  You can have a combined agenda search, or several different searches separated by blocks.  For example, you might consider forgetting about using TODO and use something more GTD like:  `(setq org-todo-keywords '((sequence "Active(a)" "Next Action(n)" "Canceled(c)" "Hold(h)" "Reference(r)" "Delegated(d)" "Waiting(w)" "Postponed(P)" "Someday(s)" "Planning(p)" "|" "None(N)")))`

Comment: What you're suggesting is "adding more structure to TODO keywords", which is what I'm doing with the `SCHEDULED` thing, isn't it? But that, somehow, is not enough. How do I mark something to be completed 'this week'? Deadline on Sunday? (My weeks go Mon-Sun :) ) (I usually use sparse trees instead of going to *Org Agenda* btw; I only use the agenda for a fixed schedule/timetable).

Comment: Another idea would be to write your own `sexp` for the `SCHEDULED:` date https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13555385/org-mode-how-to-schedule-repeating-tasks-for-the-first-saturday-of-every-month  There are a few threads on emacs.stackexchange and stackoverflow of custom `sexp` that is used by the `org-agenda` buffer.

Answer (score 2):

Your question appears to be about several things. For your two issues, use SCHEDULED for "Tasks that I just need to look at on a particular date/period." (works for date, maybe not period). Use DEADLINE for "Tasks that are indeed scheduled to be completed on a particular date.".

If your question is about scheduling things at year or month resolution, not at day resolution, that is not built into the Org Agenda as far as I know. You can add properties though, and then search on properties. Or, you could adapt this existing feature to schedule them with some noise added to the date:

http://sachachua.com/blog/2014/04/org-mode-helps-deal-ever-growing-backlog/

> Org has a built-in command for bulk-scattering tasks. From the agenda view, you can type m to mark multiple tasks, then type B and then S to scatter tasks randomly over the next N days. (Call it with a prefix argument as C-u B S to limit it to weekdays.)

Answer (score 2):

You can do agenda searches for arbitrary properties.  For example if you have an `ON_DATE` property that looks like either "2017" or "2017-07":

```
* Look at this
:PROPERTIES:
:ON_DATE:  2017
:END:

* Look this month
:PROPERTIES:
:ON_DATE:  2017-07
:END:

* Don't look at this
:PROPERTIES:
:ON_DATE:  2018
:END:
```

You can do agenda searches for items with `ON_DATE` the current year/month by using `format-time-string` to construct the query:

```
(add-to-list 'org-agenda-custom-commands
             '("Y" "Year"
              tags (format "ON_DATE=\"%s\""
                           (format-time-string "%Y"))))

(add-to-list 'org-agenda-custom-commands
             '("M" "Year"
              tags (format "ON_DATE=\"%s\""
                           (format-time-string "%Y-%m"))))
```

Warning: agenda searches for non-special properties are rather slow.

Another solution is to use tags like `year2017` `month201707` and use the same sort of idea as above to construct the search:

```
(add-to-list 'org-agenda-custom-commands
             '("M" "Year"
              tags (format "+month%s"
                           (format-time-string "%Y%m"))))
```