# Show org todos with certain tag in designated file

Tags: org-mode, todo

I want to implement a certain time-management system in emacs/org-mode.

For each project, I intend to have one .org file which includes all associated to-dos. I already created those.
Now, I would like to have one 'this month' and one 'this week' file, which show all to-dos from the above project files which I have given a corresponding tag 'this month' and 'this week'.

The 'this week' file I want to use to document my progress on the tasks, and I want to have the to-dos as headlines which I can also interactively label as 'done' from the 'this week' file, so they get shown as completed in the 'this month' and the project file.

Is this possible in emacs/org-mode? I created the project files and gave the tags, but I don't know how to create month and week files as I intend.

I've read this related thread: [SCHEDULE task for year or month](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/34037/schedule-task-for-year-or-month) but I'm more concerned with showing to-dos with certain tags in two different files. Doesn't have to be agenda.

Comment: But the agenda is made for that: add the files to the agenda and do a tags search.

Comment: @NickD Can I use agenda to create two permanent files as I described which are synced with the original file? I don't want to repeat the tags search each time.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean: are you objecting to having to specify the search each time? If so, you can add a [custom agenda search](https://orgmode.org/manual/Storing-searches.html#Storing-searches). If you are objecting to the computational cost, then I'm not sure how your setup alleviates that: can you provide more details (possibly a small example)?